# c++ insertion sort error

Tags: c++, runtime-error, insertion-sort

When I compile, it gives error of read access violation. Other stack overflow posts says this is due to an infinite loop. I also saw that the value goes to a very large negative number. My guess is that it is because list[-1], but I do not know how to change it so it does not go past list[0].

Insertion sort code

```
void insertion_sort(int list[], int length) {

for (int i = 1; i < length; i++) {
    for (int j = i; (j > 0) && (list[j] < list[j - 1]); j--) {
            swap(list, list[j - 1], list[j]);
    }
}
```

}

Swap function code

```
void swap(int list[], int & src, int & dest){ 
    int temp = list[src];
    list[src] = list[dest];
    list[dest] = temp;
}
```

Comment: Don't guess. Use the debugger. You can't seem to decide what the parameters to `swap` mean. You would have noticed this if you stepped through the code in a debugger.

Comment: Thank you, I went through it with the debugger and I realized that I was inputting the value instead of the position.

Comment: Not just inputting the value, a reference to the value. This makes it unnecessary to pass in the list. You can simply `temp = src; src = dest; dest = temp;` and let the compiler handle the rest.

Comment: Does not look to me like insertion sort. More like bubble sort.

Answer (score 1):

You are using the values of your sort as an index in your swap. Keep it simple.

This works.

```
void insertion_sort(int list[], int length) {

    for (int i = 1; i < length; i++) {
        for (int j = i; (j > 0) && (list[j] < list[j - 1]); j--) {
            std::swap( list[j - 1], list[j] );
        }
    }
}

int main( )
{

    int arr[ 100 ];
    for( size_t i= 0; i < 100; ++i )
        arr[ i ]= std::rand( );

    insertion_sort( arr, 100 );

    return 0;
}
```

Added:

As this looks like a class exercise. What you want to notice is that `std::swap` has no idea that your `list` exists. All it wants to know is what values you want to swap. So if you can't use the standard library, write your swap like the standard.

Comment: Thank you, it was a class exercise. I realized my mistake, but I am glad to learn about the std::swap. I am really new to c++

Comment: Best you can do is build on the shoulders of giants. It has all mostly been done before. As you learn, depend on the standard library, Boost, and there are a lot more specialized libraries. Proficient means you avoid reinventing wheels.

Answer (score 0):

```
void insertion_sort(int list[], int length) {

for (int i = 1; i < length; i++) {
    j = i;
    while(j > 0 && list[j - 1] > list[j]){
      swap(list, list[j], list[j-1]);
      j--;
    }
}
```

This should work for sorting least to greatest. The while loop does the job of checking if it needs to be swapped and checks the already "sorted" positions in the array if it needs to be swapped again.

Happy Coding.

Comment: Thank you, i figured it out. I was misinterpretting the swap parameters.